# show/hide mulptiple divs using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

im very new to jquery , i understand some of it but this is hitting me hard. so ive looked around for an answer but maybe im trying to be too specific.

this is the jquery code im using :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".slidingDiv").hide();
    //hides the div 

    $(".show_hide").show();
    //click on the img to show hidden div 

    $('.show_hide').click(function(){
    $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle("slow");

});


heres example of the html :

<div class">


<img height="300" width="350" src="images/web.png" alt="design 1"  class=" show_hide img-responsive center-block wow fadeIn" href="#"/>
<br>

</div>  

when i click this image , it toggles the hidden div :

<div class="slidingDiv">


          <div>


      <img height="300" width="350" src="images/web.png" alt="design 1"  class="img-responsive center-block" />

          </div>
</div>

css: 

.slidingDiv{
height:400px;
background-color:black;
padding:50px;
margin-top:10px;
margin-bottom: 35px;
border-bottom:1px solid #3399FF;
}

.show_hide{
display:none;
}
```

and this works awesome when i add "show_hide" class to the image i want to use , then the div appears nicely above when i add the class "slidingDiv" , but how do i implement this into more than one image with different divs with jquery?

i just registered today at stack so sory if im doing somethings wrong.

Comment: What is the relation of show_hide to slidingDiv? Show some HTML

Comment: show_hide is simply the class i added to the img to toggle the show/hide and "sliding div" is the class i give to the div that is hidden<div>
          

 <img height="300" width="350" src="images/web.png" alt="design 1"  class=" show_hide img-responsive center-block wow fadeIn" href="#"/>
  

   </div>

Comment: @VictorLara you really to need to include *all* of your HTML in your original question by editing it, which should also include your hidden div i.e. `slidingDiv`.

Comment: @tahir sorry about that , its my first day here

Comment: you will need to find a relation between the two; a relation that both can identify each other with (or at least your `img` can identify your `slidingDiv` with). Which should mean that you will need to modify your `img` tag to carry unique information about the connected `slidingDiv`. And your `slidingDiv` will need a unique `id` to go along with it. Getting?

Comment: @TahirAhmed yeah i tried using "slidingDiv1" , "slidingDiv2", with "show_hide1" and "show_hide2" but i wasnt sure how to do the jquery

Comment: @VictorLara, take a look at my answer and let me know if you meant something else

Comment: @VictorLara there is another way as well. I am working on both approaches. I think I know what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can do,

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".slidingDiv").hide();
    //hides the div 

    $(".show_hide").click(function(){
        $(".slidingDiv").show("slow"); 
    });


});
```

[**Here is a demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/saumil_sss/x24cd73u/3/)

If you want to make multiple div appear and disappear when you click on a single image you can add the class `slidingDiv` to those div

```
<div class="slidingDiv">
    text text text text text text text
    text text text text text text text
    text text text text text text text
    text text text text text text text
    text text text text text text text
    text text text text text text text
    text text text text text text text
    text text text text text text text
</div>
<div class="slidingDiv">
    text text text text text text text
    text text text text text text text
</div>
<div class="slidingDiv">
    text text text text text text text
    text text text text text text text
</div>
```

[**Demo for multiple images**](https://jsfiddle.net/saumil_sss/x24cd73u/4/)

Comment: @VictorLara do you mean making more than one div appear and disappear?

Comment: yes sir! im trying to figure out how to use jquery to click on an image and make a div appear

Comment: @VictorLara check out my updated answer and updated demo. Is this what you are asking for?

Comment: what about multiple images with different info ? thanks alot for your patience , im sure im having a hard time explaining myself.

Comment: @VictorLara check my new demo at the end of the answer, is this what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

With the `HTML` setup you have, you will want to navigate up and then to the sibling `.slidingDiv` like

```
$('.show_hide').click(function() {
        $(this).closest('div').next(".slidingDiv").slideToggle("slow");
      });
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".slidingDiv").hide();
  //hides the div 

  $(".show_hide").show();
  //click on the img to show hidden div 

  $('.show_hide').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('div').next(".slidingDiv").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
```

```css
.slidingDiv {

  height: 75px;

  background-color: black;

  padding: 50px;

  margin-top: 10px;

  margin-bottom: 35px;

  border-bottom: 1px solid #3399FF;

}

.show_hide {

  display: none;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>


  <img height="30" width="35" src="images/web.png" alt="design 1" class=" show_hide img-responsive center-block wow fadeIn" href="#" />
  <br>

</div>



<div class="slidingDiv">


  <div>


    <img height="30" width="35" src="images/web.png" alt="design 1" class="img-responsive center-block" />

  </div>
</div>

<div>


  <img height="30" width="35" src="images/web.png" alt="design 1" class=" show_hide img-responsive center-block wow fadeIn" href="#" />
  <br>

</div>



<div class="slidingDiv">


  <div>


    <img height="30" width="35" src="images/web.png" alt="design 1" class="img-responsive center-block" />

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: omg thanks alot!! i understand now!  both this version and saumil's version works great! thanks alot for the help sir!

Comment: @VictorLara, the difference between my version and the other is this version you dont have to name classes show_hide1, show_hide2, rather, `$(this)` is used to navigate to closest one. This means less code

Comment: yeah i noticed that , ima try to learn from both ways. again thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

Although you seem to have found your solution but to provide you with another alternative, i.e. if you are interested in the first place, [here is what I have been able to produce](http://jsfiddle.net/tahirahmed/mfenv6yu/). This is an overly simplistic example mind you and the intention is to provide you with an idea.

The way it works is that it would get the [`index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/) of clicked element out of elements that are click-able and it would apply this `index()` on the set of other elements that need to be animated with the help of [`eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) method.

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.image-container').on('click',function(){
        $('.sliding-div').eq($(this).index()).stop().slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Benefit of using this approach is that you don't have to repeat code. Another benefit is that your `sliding-div` elements do not necessarily have to remain close to `image-container` elements in HTML, they can be wherever they need to be in the markup. But the disadvantage is that it is strictly dependant on the order with which HTML markup has been laid out. So, for example, if second element out of `image-container` elements is clicked, the second element out of `sliding-div` elements will be animated.

Hope this helps in some way.